# Tensorflow control_dependencies not forcing specified operator to be ran first

Tags: python, tensorflow

Today I noticed some strange behaviour in Tensorflow and thought I'd ask here to understand what's happening. My problem revolves around `tf.control_dependencies` not making the specified operator being run before the operators I define inside the `with` block. What I am asking here is not how to compute the performance metrics (I coded that manually), but rather where my misconception lies.

So, to set the scene. Today, I made some code to log performance metrics during training of a CNN, and I was using the `tensorflow.metrics` module for this. However, the operators in this module cumulate the previous results (so performance metrics can be computed for very large datasets). I want to log how the metrics evolve over time as the network train, so I don't want this behaviour. Therefore, I wrapped the creation of these performance metrics nodes in a `tf.control_dependencies`, forcing (or so I thought) a `tf.local_variables_initialiser` to be evaluated before my performance metrics is computed. Thus, my code could look like this

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(10))
out = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(10, 1))

with tf.control_dependencies([tf.local_variables_initializer()]):
    _, precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels, out)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(precision))
```

but when I try to run the above code, I get the following error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value precision_4/true_positives/count
     [[Node: precision_4/true_positives/AssignAdd = AssignAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@precision_4/true_positives/count"], use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](precision_4/true_positives/count, precision_4/true_positives/Sum)]]
```

now, I have encountered this error many times while I tried to understand the `metrics` module and the reason for it is that I have not initialised my variables properly. Therefore, I tested this code

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(10))
out = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(10, 1))

with tf.control_dependencies([tf.local_variables_initializer()]):
    _, precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels, out)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(precision))
```

which does indeed work.

**So my question remains**. Why is the `tf.local_variables_initializer()` node not ran before the performance metrics are computed in my first code example?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed really strange. I guess you need to place

```
 _, precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels, out)
```

before the `control_dependencies` like

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.arange(10))
out = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(10, 1))

_, _precision = tf.metrics.precision(labels, out)

with tf.control_dependencies([tf.local_variables_initializer()]):
    # precision = tf.identity(_precision)
    precision = 1 * _precision

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(precision))
```

This works like expected as the local variables of `tf.metrics.precision` do exist before calling `tf.local_variables_initializer`. In your code, the `tf.local_variables_initializer` is executed before the node `precision`. Hence, `precision_4/true_positives/count` cannot exists and therefore not initialized, simply because the graph is not existing.

To make it even more strange (which seems to be a bug):
Placing `precision = 1 * precision` in the body of `control_dependencies` works. But `precision = tf.identity(precision)` does not.

This is a good candidate for a bug in TensorFlow.

Comment: I tried the `precision = 1*precision` trick myself, and it works over 99% of the time. However, sometimes, it will not work.I tried the `precision = 1*precision` trick myself, and it works over 99% of the time. However, sometimes, it will not work. I assume this is because with this trick, the "old" precision node can still be computed before the "new" node, it is only the times one part that needs to be computed after initialisation.

Comment: As long as you are executing the same code on a deterministic Turing machine, there is *not* such a thing as it sometimes works and sometimes not. Then you changed some other stuff.

Comment: Problem is that it is not deterministic as the computations are performed in parallel.

Comment: To illustrate, name precision node `P1`, its inputs `X` and `Y`, the initialiser `I` and `P2=1*P1`. Also, imagine that we have two CPU cores, CPU1 and CPU2. The first time around, CPU1 starts to compute `X`, CPU2 manages to compute `Y` and `I` before `X` finishes. `P1` requires `X`, `Y` and `I` to function so it is not evaluated before `X` is  computed. `X` is computed and the evaluation of `P1` succeeds. _(continued in next comment)_

Comment: The next time we try this, the load on CPU2 is heavy, so it doesn't manage to finish `I` before `X` is finished. While CPU2 tries to compute `I`, CPU1 starts computing `P1` and fails as not everything is initialised. The key observation here is that `P2` requires `I` before it is loaded onto a CPU core, wheras tensorflow will try to evaluate `P1` and fail.

Comment: No! The graph is serial meaning the node will not start before all child nodes are evaluated. This is very likely a bug (either in the implementation or documentation), following the documentation of `tf.control_dependencies` which ensures to evaluate stuff **before**.

Comment: But the point of my question was that `I` is not added as a dependency of `P1`. Also, I had already tried a the same idea as you wrote in your answe, and it did fail about one percent of the time (using for loops to create new sessions each time).